# Survey monkey - add cool down to survey response

Tags: surveymonkey

Does anyone know if it is possible to add a cool down on survey monkey?

My website currently sends out emails requesting people to complete a survey after a transaction. I have a 1 month cool down on that email to ensure I'm not bombarding people however from survey monkey side, they can only complete the survey once, meaning subsequent visits just get the "You've already done this survey" message.

I don't want the survey to be 100% repeatable (we all know there will be that one guy who sends 100 surveys because he got out of the wrong side of his bed).

So I'm looking to add a cool down to survey monkey, to allow people to take the survey more than once with a 1 month cool down.

I have searched through their docs but I can't find anything relating to this. Just wondering if anyone else has run into and solved this problem?

Thanks in advance